# Объединить в один список после функции map

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется функция возвращающая несколько элементов, имеется массив данных, который необходимо обработать этой функцией, при использовании функции map данные возвращаются в tuple. Есть ли возможность их объединить сразу в 1 список?

```
def func(x):
    return x, x * 2

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = list(map(func, a))
print(b) # [(1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 6)]
```

Хотелось бы

```
[1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 6]
```

Нашел такой вариант, но данных очень много и не хотелось бы еще раз их обрабатывать.

```
l1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
print(sum(l1, [])) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так можно:

```
def func(x):
    return x, x * 2

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = []
for res in map(func, a):
    b.extend(res)
print(b) # [1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 5):

Методом из вашего вопроса (лямбда нужна чтобы преобразовать значение, которое вернула функция `func`, в список, иначе будет ошибка типизации при попытке сложить кортеж и список):

```
b = sum(map(lambda x: list(func(x)), a), [])
```

С помощью [`chain` из `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain


def func(x):
    return x, x * 2


a = [1, 2, 3]
b = list(chain(*map(func, a)))
# или b = list(chain.from_iterable(map(func, a)))
print(b)  # [1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 6]
```

[`chain.from_iterable(something)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.chain.from_iterable) эквивалентно `chain(*something)`, что использовать - дело вкуса.

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain.from_iterable(map(func, a)))
```

```
[1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 6]
```

Comment: Лучше приводить код без `>>>`, чтобы можно было его легко скопировать и запустить у себя

Comment: @dIm0n Спасибо, буду знать.